# how to load tflite(learned model) in browser?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js, yolov5

I want to use an already learned model from https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/releases.
How to load tflite in browser?

Answer (score 0):

**tflite** support for **TFJS** is quite new and still experimental, but you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow/tfjs-tflite

Also note that TFLite models are executed using `WASM` backend, no other option (mostly due to original philosophy of tflite which is CPU execution of int quantized models for consumption on the edge where GPU or FPU are not that prevalent)

Comment: Thank you so much for letting us know. :)